# SpringMvc + Cloud SQL (MySQL) integration

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, google-cloud-sql

In my project, we are planning to use google cloud SQL. But I do not have complete steps to proceed this. I have created a database and table in the cloud SQL shell. How do I need to connect that database from spring MVC project? Please give clear steps to proceed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples) official documentation by Spring Cloud for Google Cloud Platform which provides code samples and examples. What you want to do is described [in this link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-mysql-sample) for MySQL or [in this link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-postgres-sample) for PostgreSQL.

There is also this [community's tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql) which can guide you through the creation of a Spring Boot application with Cloud SQL on App Engine Flexible environment.

I also found [this](https://medium.com/@DazWilkin/google-cloud-sql-4-ways-spring-a4f13ad32714) article which is not official document but it can help you to understand better the way you can handle Cloud SQL in your project.

Comment: @Sangeetha in case this answer helped you in solving your issue, could you accept it? Thanks!